How to compute the matched filter of an IIR filter given its z-domain or Laplace-domain transfer function?
Let's consider
$$
H(z) = \frac{b_2 z^2 + b_1 z + b_0}{a_2 z^2 + a_1 z + a_0}
$$
Is it possible to express the matched filter (the filter that maximizes the SNR in receivers) of $H(z)$ and express it under the form of a transfer function of the variable $z$ only (without $z^\ast$, the conjugate of $z$) ?

Normally a matched filter is matched to a signal, not a filter.  Also normally, there are constraints on the nature of the signal you're trying to detect (no intersymbol interference, in simple models).  Please edit your question with more information about what you're actually trying to do (i.e. "I want to make a radar to detect where my cows are").  Then we can help you achieve your end goal.

You're right, Tim.  I s'pose we could define the "signal" as the impulse response of a filter.

You are right, I made a very short description of my problem on purpose but I did not expect to over been oversimplifying. @Matt L. provided an answer that is satisfying for me

As mentioned in a comment, it's a bit unclear what you're asking, but if you're looking for the transfer function of a filter which, when concatenated with the given $H(z)$, results in the frequency response $|H(e^{j\omega})|^2$, then the answer is
$$G(z)=H^*\left(\frac{1}{z^*}\right)\tag{1}$$
where $^*$ means complex conjugation. Note that the conjugation of $H()$ and the conjugation of the argument $1/z$ cancel each other, i.e., you end up with a function of $z$, not of $z^*$.
If the filter coefficients are real-valued, then $(1)$ simplifies to
$$G(z)=H\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\tag{2}$$
We have
\begin{align*}
H^*\left(\frac{1}{z^*}\right) &= \left(\frac{b_2\left(\frac{1}{z^*}\right)^2+b_1\left(\frac{1}{z^*}\right)+b_0}{a_2\left(\frac{1}{z^*}\right)^2+a_1\left(\frac{1}{z^*}\right)+a_0}\right)^* \\
&= \frac{b_0^*z^2+b_1^*z+b_2^*}{a_0^*z^2+a_1^*z+a_2^*}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
From $(3)$ we see that the coefficient vectors are flipped and conjugated (if they're complex-valued).
If $H(z)$ is causal and stable then $H^*(1/z^*)$ is anti-causal and stable. Hence, it cannot be realized directly. One option is to add some delay, truncate the impulse response, and implement the remaining part of the impulse response by an FIR filter.
